# How do I define an alias for an include directory in my MakeFile?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

My project repository has the following structure:

```
include
---- world
src
```

In my MakeFile, I include the headers like so:

```
INCLUDES = -I include
```

However, for reasons outside of the scope of this question, I would like to refer to my include directory with an alias. For example, one of my cpp files may include a header as follows:

```
#include <hello/world/test.h>
```

My question is, how do I define an alias that refers to my include directory to achieve this?

Comment: How do you mean "alias"? A variable within the makefile?

Comment: I don't know of any way to do what you want. Assuming what you want is to pretend you have a "hello" directory in your sources instead of `include` (short of creating a symlink).

Comment: You want to trick the tool that reads your `#include` statements into believing that `world` is in `hello` where it really isn't.  That tool is the C preprocessor, not `make`, so you have to think of something that the C preprocessor will fall for. Whatever you come up with, it is going to be convoluted and confusing. Creating a symlink: `ln -s hello .` seems the best approach.